Getting execution time for each query without logging
In our Spring Boot (MVC) app, we're trying to log the amount of time taken to execute every SQL query / statement (or the amount of time taken for each transaction since I don't believe that's possible at the statement level). We're using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate, and are open to an AOP solution if others aren't feasible.
I'm aware of some existing methods, but they don't fit our needs. For example, while Hibernate can log execution time for each query, we want to actually capture the execution time in Java as a long for each query/statement/transaction to perform further processing. I'm also aware of QueryStatistics, but it captures aggregated execution time statistics rather than individual execution times.
Here's a pseudo-code example of what I'm trying to do if I were to do it with Spring AOP:
@Around(<pointcut referring to each query, statement, or transaction being executed>)
public Object aroundQueryExecution(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
  StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
  timer.start();
  Object result = jp.proceed(jp.getArgs());
  timer.stop();
  long time = timer.getTotalTimeMillis();
  // Do other business logic with `time` ...
}

Again, we're flexible with what type of solution this can be - an interceptor, AOP, an existing Hibernate functionality I'm not aware of, etc.
If possible, we'd also like to be able to capture the query String itself along with the execution time.

I think, it would be helpful to publish an MCVE on GitHub. It is hard to reason and say anything intelligent about invisible code. BTW, in your code is the StopWatch instance meant to be named timer, so it fits with the rest of the code?

@kriegaex thanks good catch, edited the question. I don't feel an MCVE is warranted here as this is focused on design rather than debugging - there's not really any relevant code here besides the existing example.

use a datasource proxy would be better here. we can do a lot of things in the proxy.  for quick integrate to your spring-boot project, we can refer spring-boot-data-source-decorator. it provides 3 kinds of proxy libraries.

If an MCVE is not warranted, your question is off topic here. The way this platform works is that you provide a reproducible problem and the community helps you to fix it. It is not a free coding-on-demand service where others do your job for you. How can you expect anyone to suggest a pointcut without knowing the target code?

What is your question? You seem to have forgotten to ask one.

@kriegaex No, it's not off topic - you clearly just didn't read the whole thing. First, I never said it had to be a pointcut - I merely brought up the possibility of a pointcut as it'd be a logical way to find the execution time of a query (which I blatantly state is my goal multiple times... finding the execution time of each query).
And I'm sorry, no MCVE, not warranted on SO? Are you high? I present to you, the second most upvoted question in SO history

@Jiandong Great suggestion, I'll have to look into those, thank you!

Comparing apples and pears does not make the MCVE here less relevant. That other question is an order of magnitude more trivial than yours and also clearer in scope. But up to you, nobody is forcing you to provide an MCVE, it was just a friendly suggestion. You are, however, shooting your own foot like this, because the way your question looks right now, a good answer is difficult to come by and therefore unlikely. Good luck anyway.

@kriegaex Counterpoint: Jiandong already answered my question without an MCVE...

That was a comment, not an answer. Of course, sometimes you get lucky and a comment or an answer based on an educated guess yields a helpful solution. Congrats that you seem to be lucky in this case. But you did not even ask a question, especially not one that has a correct answer. At best, your "question" results in opinionated answers, which is off topic here.
